# CSS - Justify the tabs

Tags: html, css

I am working with a shopping cart script, and there's tabs that contains the product categories.

Here's the tabs css :

```
 .paypalshop .shop-groups{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #ddd;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.paypalshop .shop-groups li{
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }

.paypalshop .shop-groups a{
 display: block;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 min-width: 20px;
 padding: 2px 15px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #777; 
 font-weight: bold;
 text-shadow:0 1px 1px #fff;
}

.paypalshop .shop-groups a:hover{
 color: #555;
}

.paypalshop .shop-groups .active-group {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.paypalshop .shop-groups .active-group a{
 color: #da0000!important;
 }
```

The thing is that in my project, I have 9 categories, and it wraps the other tabs under.
(see what I mean here : http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg607/scaled.php?server=607&filename=screenshot20120516at170.png&res=landing)

As you can see, it does not look very good the way it is...because the tabs buttons does not fill the top bar width.

Is there a way to "justify" the buttons tabs? (in the CSS up there, it is .paypalshop .shop-groups a)

So it would look like : http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg27/scaled.php?server=27&filename=toptabs.jpg&res=landing

Any idea how? It needs to be done modifying the CSS I pasted here.

Thank you!

---

EDIT : Here's how 2 categories are made in my HTML code :

```
 <!-- group1-->
<ul id="Presentoirs">
<li class="product" name="Geotop" price="20.5"> 
                         <a class="product-image fancybox" href="images/product_big.jpg" title="Picture 4">
                             <img src="images/product_2.png" alt="Preview"/>
                             <div class="text-overlay">
                              <p class="product-heading">Description</p>
                               Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                               doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore 
                               veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                             </div>
                         </a>
                         <p class="product-heading">Geotop</p>
                         <a href="#" class="product-buy">Ajouter au panier</a>
                         <p class="product-meta">some additional comment</p>
                         <div class="product-price">20.5<span class="product-currency">$</span></div>
                    </li>
</ul>

 <!-- group2-->
<ul id="Bannieres_et_Supports_en_A">
<li class="product" name="Geotop" price="20.5"> 
                         <a class="product-image fancybox" href="images/product_big.jpg" title="Picture 4">
                             <img src="images/product_2.png" alt="Preview"/>
                             <div class="text-overlay">
                              <p class="product-heading">Description</p>
                               Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium
                               doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore 
                               veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
                             </div>
                         </a>
                         <p class="product-heading">Geotop</p>
                         <a href="#" class="product-buy">Ajouter au panier</a>
                         <p class="product-meta">some additional comment</p>
                         <div class="product-price">20.5<span class="product-currency">$</span></div>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what does your HTML look like?

Comment: You should have each element be X % width of the container its in based on the number of object. So if you have a row of 4 items, set all the widths to be 25%. 25 x 4 = 100% of the space.

Comment: The thing is that the top container with the tabs button in it is only 1 container. So if I would have 2 categories, It would look like : http://gravitysign.com/paypalShop2/
.
Since I have 9 categories in my project, it wraps the other tabs under when it reach the container width...and it looks like the first link I have put in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child` propriety and add specific `width` for every tab.

[Read about :nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)